# difference between (*head)->next and &(*head)->next in C [LINKED LIST]

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
typedef struct n {
    int data;
    struct n *next;
}node;
```

This function deletes all nodes with odd values (without freeing memory or additional variables) :

```
void deleteOdds (node **head) {

    if (*head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    while ((*head)->next) {

        if ((*head)->data % 2 != 0) {
            *head = (*head)->next;
        } else head = &(*head)->next;
    }

}
```

I understand the logic (and already have some assumptions), but I'm not sure how to explain the difference between

```
*head =(*head)->next;
```

and

```
head = &(*head)->next;
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `head = &(*head)->next;` is most likely a mistake. Where did you see this code?

Comment: @M.M No, it's not a mistake. `head` is a bad name, a better name should be `current`. `head = &(*head)->next` simply makes `next` the new `current`; the syntax is complex because of a two-star pointer.

Comment: @4386427 Note that `head` is a pointer to pointer, so when we move it to something reachable from the original head, or replace it with another head, our changes remain observable outside the function.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight can you explain why  the parameter is `node **head` and not `node *head` then? It suggests an in-out parameter. The line `*head = (*head)->next;` moves this node pointer, informing the caller.  However after the line `head = &(*head)->next;` , the caller will not see this and the caller's argument will no longer be updated.  So the caller's pointer will advance up to the first even number, and then stay there even though there were later even and odd numbers deleted

Comment: @M.M This is the unfortunate consequence of the need to modify the head in the caller (e.g. `main` would call this function like this: `struct n *head; /* populate the list here*/ deleteOdds(&head);` Without passing a pointer to pointer, i.e. with `deleteOdds(head)` the function wouldn't be able to delete the head node itself if it happens to have an odd value.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight do you not see that writing `head =` in the function now makes it so that the caller no longer will see changes? `head` is a local variable to the function.

Comment: @M.M Of course I see it :-) However, `head`, which is local to `deleteOdds`, is assigned only when `head` from the caller points to a node with even data or `NULL`. Otherwise, the loop keeps assigning `*head`. After the assignment we don't care about changes to the `head` in the caller - in fact, once the first re-assignment of `head` itself has happened, we could stop using a pointer to pointer, and switch to using a regular pointer the way you suggested in your comment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OK, I did a desk check and see what's going on now. The code doesn't 'delete' the last node in the list even if it's odd. Thanks for being patient with me :) Agree with your comment that 'head' is a poor name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding what's going on is to see what is being assigned in each case:

- `*head = (*head)->next;` assigns to whatever `head` is pointing to, which is either the original head pointer, the pointer to which is passed to the function, or a `next` of some prior node. We modify what is pointed to, while the pointer stays the same. This amounts to deleting from the list (and creating a memory leak in the process).
- `head = &(*head)->next` assigns to the `head` itself, i.e. it modifies the pointer, not the thing that it points to. This amounts to skipping ahead in the list, without modifying it.

**Note:** `head` is not the ideal name for the variable. Since the variable points to `head` pointer only until the first "skip", a better name for it would be `current`.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. head really is a clumsy name.